# How to change tabbar on Swift (xCode)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbar, tabbar

How change tabbar?

1. positioning an image
2. width central button
3. white color is not selected button

[image tabbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRAT3.png)

Answer (score 0):

3. decided.

Written in func viewDidLoad (class:UITabBarController)

```
    for item in self.tabBar.items! {
        if let tabBarItem = item as? UITabBarItem {
            tabBarItem.image = tabBarItem.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
        }
    }
```